Forcing ESRI World Imagery to render next-best imagery if imagery is not available at that scale
When using ESRI World Imagery, if there is no imagery associated with the current zoom scale of the map, it shows an error: "Map data not yet available".
Is it possible to force the layer to render imagery using the closest valid zoom level/scale? For instance, if no imagery is available at scale 1:3000 but it is available for 1:1500, I'd like to force it to render the 1:1500 imagery when I'm viewing the map at 1:3000, instead of displaying this error message.


Sometimes no really does mean no. In fact, it pretty much always means that in cached map services.
